# incorrect results for retrieving all the rows from right table and matching rows from left table using right join

Tags: sql-server, join

I am working on retrieving data from two `SQL tables on SQL Server` in which I am trying to get all rows from right table along with the matching rows in left table and making other columns null

For example I have two tables named `products` and `Deals` with following data

**Products table**

```
Id Product
1  ABC
2  XYZ
3  PQR
```

**Deals Table**

```
Id  TradeDate  Product Volume   Price    Delivery
56  2014-12-08  ABC     2500    -3.25   2015-01-01 
57  2014-12-08  ABC     2500    -3.4    2015-01-01 
63  2014-12-08  PQR     2500    -7      2015-01-01 
64  2014-12-08  PQR     2500    -7      2015-01-01
```

I applied following query to the above tables

```
SELECT
         FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy') AS Delivery,

         b.Product,COUNT(a.Id) AS Trades, 
         ROUND(((6.2898*SUM(a.Volume ))/DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery), 0))))*0.001,4) AS BBLperDay,
         SUM(a.Volume) AS M3,       
         ROUND(SUM(a.Volume*a.Price)/Sum(a.Volume),4) AS WeightedAverage
FROM     Deals AS a right outer join Products AS b ON a.Product=b.Product
WHERE    CAST(a.TradeDate as date)='2014-12-08' 
GROUP BY b.Product,CAST(a.TradeDate as date), 
         DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery),0),  FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy')
```

And I got following results

```
Delivery     Product    Trades  BBLperDay   M3  WeightedAverage
January 2015    ABC        2    1.0145  5000     -3.325
January 2015    PQR        2    1.0145  5000      -7
```

But I want to include all the entries from products table keeping other fields NULL as follows

```
Delivery      Product   Trades  BBLperDay   M3  WeightedAverage
January 2015    ABC        2    1.0145      5000     -3.325
NULL            XYZ      NULL   NULL        NULL     NULL
January 2015    PQR        2    1.0145      5000      -7
```

as seen in the above results it can seen that even the product XYZ is included in it which is what I wanted

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4db19/2
**Is there a better way I could do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try moving the date criteria to the ON clause, because this way you eliminate the row which is supposed to appear with the right join, through the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
         FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy') AS Delivery,

         b.Product,COUNT(a.Id) AS Trades, 
         ROUND(((6.2898*SUM(a.Volume ))/DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery), 0))))*0.001,4) AS BBLperDay,
         SUM(a.Volume) AS M3,       
         ROUND(SUM(a.Volume*a.Price)/Sum(a.Volume),4) AS WeightedAverage
FROM     Deals AS a right outer join Products AS b 
         ON a.Product=b.Product 
         AND CAST(a.TradeDate as date)='2014-12-08' 
GROUP BY b.Product,CAST(a.TradeDate as date), 
         DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery),0),  FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `WHERE` clause, which is excluding the results where the record doesn't exist.  Try this:

```
SELECT
         FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy') AS Delivery,

         b.Product,COUNT(a.Id) AS Trades, 
         ROUND(((6.2898*SUM(a.Volume ))/DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery), 0))))*0.001,4) AS BBLperDay,
         SUM(a.Volume) AS M3,       
         ROUND(SUM(a.Volume*a.Price)/Sum(a.Volume),4) AS WeightedAverage
FROM     Deals AS a right outer join Products AS b ON a.Product=b.Product
WHERE    CAST(a.TradeDate as date)='2014-12-08' OR a.TradeDate IS NULL
GROUP BY b.Product,CAST(a.TradeDate as date), 
         DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,a.Delivery),0),  FORMAT(a.Delivery,'MMMM yyyy')
```

with the addition of `OR a.TradeDate IS NULL` in the `WHERE` clause.